# How to disable an eventhandler when another is getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, coffeescript

I have two event listeners on one input field. One gets called on change and one when you click on an autocomplete dropdown from google. My problem is when you click on such a autocompletion both handlers get called and make the request to the google api.

I tried to bind the onchange event and unbind it when the google autocomplete ajax call get fired, but the onchange event is executed first. So it will not get unbinded.
So, is there any possibility to detect if the user made the input manually or via autosugesstion? I want to execute the "requestlocation" function only when the user makes a manually input and doesn't use the autocomplete dropdown.
I tried it with some other eventhandler like "focus-out", but without success.

This line makes the bind:

```
autoCompleteInput.on "change", requestlocation
```

This is the function which get called:

```
requestlocation = () ->
  address = autoCompleteInput.val()
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
  geocoder.geocode
    address: address, (results, status) ->
      if status is google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK

        if results[0].address_components.length > 1
          city = results[0].address_components[0].long_name
          country = results[0].address_components[results[0].address_components.length-1].long_name
          setHiddenFields results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), city, country 
          autoCompleteInput.val(city+", "+country)
        else
          city = null
          country = results[0].address_components[0].long_name
          setHiddenFields results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng(), city, country
          autoCompleteInput.val(country)
        setMarker new google.maps.LatLng(latInput.val(), lngInput.val())
      else
        console.log "Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status
```

This is the code where the autocomplete handler makes the request:

```
google.maps.event.addListener autocomplete, 'place_changed', ->
  autoCompleteInput.off "change", requestlocation

  place = autocomplete.getPlace()

  if !!place.geometry
    autoCompleteInput.attr "data-valid", "true"
    setMarker place.geometry.location
    address = place.address_components
    if address.length > 1
      setHiddenFields place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng(), address[0].long_name, address[address.length-1].long_name
    else
      setHiddenFields place.geometry.location.lat(), place.geometry.location.lng(), null, address[0].long_name
  else
    autoCompleteInput.attr "data-valid", "false"

  autoCompleteInput.on "change", requestlocation
```

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First  approach: listen to the `keyup` event instead of `change`, determine the type of key press in the handler (filter out arrow keys, tab and return key) and only call `requestlocation` if an appropriate change has happened. May not really work because text can be pasted into the input field which won't trigger any key events.

Next try: use a small timeout and stop it if the autocompletion event fires.

```
autocomplete.on "change", ->
  # stop previous timeouts
  clearTimeout autocomplete.data('timeout')
  # start a new timeout and store reference
  timeout = setTimeout requestlocation, 100
  autocomplete.data timeout: timeout
```

In your autocompletion handler you should kill the running timeout and perform your call:

```
google.maps.event.addListener autocomplete, 'place_changed', ->
  # stop any running timeout
  clearTimeout autocomplete.data('timeout')
  # perform your autocompletion calls
  place = autocomplete.getPlace()
  ...
```

This also prevents multiple calls when multiple `change` events are fired rapidly. You might need to tweak the timeout (here: 100ms) to a suiting value.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how "requestlocation" looks like. But how about checking the different event properties of the change event. (event.target / event.currentTarget) I cannot test it right now, but maybe you can find there a difference. Just an idea

```
function requestlocation(event) {
  console.log(event.target, event.currentTarget);
}

var timeout;
autoCompleteInput.on("input", function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(requestlocation, 100);
});
```

Sorry about the plain javascript but I am not into coffeescript :/

Comment: Unfortunately there is no difference between target and currentTarget in requestlocation. However, I recognized that the autocomplete event listener has no event object... but this doesn't help me either.

Comment: how about switching to the "input" event? not sure whether this works when the input changes via JS (this works only in modern browsers so I do not know whether it is an option)

Comment: just made a small test... at least in Chrome the "input" event is only fired by manual input... but if another event listener changes the content the input listener does not trigger... (as a side note: in browser that does not support the input event you could also use the "keyup" event)

Comment: That would work, but the problem is that I insert the result from requestlocation to the input field. The listener "input" makes the request from the first written letter and replaces the text in the input with the first result. I would need something that waits till the user is finished with writing.

Comment: Ok a little bit tricky... You could use a throttling mechanism

Comment: I added to the Code part a delayed input... this will only trigger if the user stops typing for more than 100ms, you should this delay in your own case and adapt if needed

Comment: This kind of works, but I'm not happy with the result. As it makes an ajax call to the google api for every written letter.